# test script is giving error when window tab is closed by itself

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

In my application there is a feature when report is submitted the report tab will close automatically, but in automation I am getting below error, how to solve this problem?

error is

```
D:\e2eWorkspace\fem_e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:580                                                              
  throw new ctor(value['message'] + '');                                                                                      
        ^                                                                                                                     
NoSuchWindowError: no such window: target window already closed                                                                   
from unknown error: web view not found                                                                                            
(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.87)                                                                                             
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)        
at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\e2eWorkspace\fem_e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:580:13)                       
at D:\e2eWorkspace\fem_e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:360:15                                            
at Promise.invokeCallback_ (D:\e2eWorkspace\fem_e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)                   
at TaskQueue.execute_ (D:\e2eWorkspace\fem_e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)                        
at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (D:\e2eWorkspace\fem_e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)                    
at asyncRun (D:\e2eWorkspace\fem_e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27)                                  
at D:\e2eWorkspace\fem_e2e\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7                                               
at <anonymous>                                                                                                                
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

My code is

```
// below steps opens the report in new tab
reportPO.notSubmittedButton.first().click();
browser.sleep(6000);
browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
  var secondWindowHandle = handles[1];
  // switching to report tab
  browser.switchTo().window(secondWindowHandle).then(function () {
    browser.sleep(6000);
    /**
     * here, steps to add values in the form fields
     */
    browser.driver.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);').then(function () {
      // below step - click on save button on report
      reportPO.saveButtonOnReport.click();
      // here I am  validating the message
      commonPO.notifyMsg.getText().then(function (actualResult) {
        expect(actualResult).toEqual(MessagesPD.pilotReportNotSubmitted.message);
      });
      // before report tab closing, I am  switching driver back to parent tab
       browser.switchTo().window(originalHandle).then(function () {
         console.log('moved');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: what do you do when submit the report?

Comment: Before submitting form you can switch to default drive window

Comment: @Oleksii report means, there is a form which needs to be submitted and it is mandatory, when this form is opened in new tab and when it is submitted, the window closes by itself.

Comment: @AnkurSingh i tried even this before tab getting closed, i tried switching back to parent tab, even then it is not working

Comment: It's submitting that form our closing ?

Comment: @SuhailAhmed You need to share your execution code, How it is handling and what went wrong.

Comment: @IshitaShah i added my code in above description.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to previous tab using this code:

```
 browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
            newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
            browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);
 });
```